# How to find such U and V such that U$\cap$V=$\emptyset$

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Assume that A and B are closed disjoint subsets. Then there exist open sets U$\supset$A and V$\supset$B with U$\cap$V =$\emptyset$

I am said to deduce it from (Urysohn's Lemma). Let A, B be two disjoint closed subsets of a metric space. There exists a continuous function f: X$\rightarrow$R such that 0$\leq$f$\leq$1 and f = 0 on A and f = 1  on B. To prove this one i considered the function f(x)= $\frac{d_A(x)}{d_A(x)+d_B(x)}$ as suggested and proved the following. But i have no idea how to use this to conclude
  U$\cap$V=$\emptyset$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your function is particular for a metric space. In this case, it is well defined, is equal to $1$ exactly on $B$ and to $0$ exactly on $A$. Moreover, it is continuous so that the preimage of any open subset of $[0,1]$ is open in $E$. Let $U = f^{-1}([0,1/4))$ and $V=f^{-1}((3/4,1])$. Prove they are solutions of your problem.

Comment: So A= $f^{-1}$ ({0})$\subset$U?

Comment: Yes. Same thing for $B$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Choose an open around $0$ in the codomain and an open around $1$ in the codomain disjoint from this other open and let $U$ and $V$ their inverse images.